# Android. Sudden problem with emulator, physical device works fine

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having some problem with developing an android app. Everything runs smooth until a while ago. Lately I've been debugging on a couple of different physical devices and everything works great on all of them. The other day when I tried to run the application in the emulator I got an error:

`ERROR/JNIHelp(313): Native registration unable to find class 'android/debug/JNITest'`.

Is this something to worry about? The app is supposed to be released today on the market but it doesn't feel right to release something that wont even load in the emulator. Since the app works seemingly flawless on all physical devices I've tested it might not be a problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your emulator img and starting again with a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -wipe-data ... if it doesn't work, delete the emulator images .. and if that doesn't work re-install the SDK .. No other fancy solution, afaik.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the emulator images was the solution. I've tried -wipe-data without success erlier :)